# Setting the right projection for a georeferenced PNG image

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have been trying to georeference an image I downloaded from Google API.
Here is how I approached it after many unsuccessful attempts:

1. I calculated the coordinates of the corners using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106276/converting-pixels-to-latlng-coordinates-from-google-static-image).
2. I added the transforms using the bounds coordinates and the CRS value. I used the CRS value suggested in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet) for Google Maps images.

```py
    def georefrence(input_path, output_path):
        dataset = rasterio.open(input_path)
        bands = [1]
        data = dataset.read(bands)
        transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(xmax, ymax,xmin, ymin, data.shape[1], data.shape[2])
        crs = rasterio.crs.CRS({"init": "epsg:3857"})
        with rasterio.open(output_path, 'w', driver='GTiff',
                    width=data.shape[1], height=data.shape[2],
                    count=3, dtype=data.dtype, nodata=0,
                    transform=transform, crs=crs) as dst:
      dst.write(data, indexes=bands)
```

3. When I load the image in QGIS, I see pick a coordinate, copy it, and paste it in Google map. It doesn't map to the exact location but is pretty close; however, when I try to display it in OSM layer map, it appears in way off.

Is this a projection issue or something else and how can I resolve this?

**UPDATE**

So here is a sample image that I georeferenced
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVgHrv6AJ28X8GSsF9sSaIVQcjldBsSR/view?usp=sharing

I figured that when I add the GeoTIFF version as a raster layer to QGIS on the OSM base map, it shows in the exact opposite location up (see the image below).
[image]

How can I mirror this? Is it the projection or something else?

**UPDATE 2**

Another thing that I noticed is that when I paste these coordinates 30.0768254,31.6577946 in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps), it points out the correct location, but when I paste it into Google Maps base map in QGIS, I go to the Atlantic Ocean.

Worth to note that I have already sat the CRS to EPSG: 3857 for the base map also (the same CRS of the image)

Comment: Which google API did you download the image from?  Did you check whether the file already is georeferenced (using gdalinfo)?

Comment: @nmtoken it is not georefrenced just a png image. We are getting it from Google static API. Will include an example

Comment: @nmtoken Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer below helped figure it out
[Lat/Long co-ordinates are not plotting onto EPSG:3857 OSM basemap correctly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340677/lat-long-co-ordinates-are-not-plotting-onto-epsg3857-osm-basemap-correctly)

I realized that the lat and long were mixed up, and after a few inspections, it turned out that I made a big mistake in putting the bounds in the right order
in this line

```
transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(...)
```